# ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.RFA

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I installed Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.13 on virtualbox and I'm trying to start hadoop server with the command `sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start` but 'm getting this two errors:
`log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.RFA` and `log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "RFA"`.
Can anyone can help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you find the log4j file that's used and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my log4j.properties file (my case ./workspace/training/conf/log4j.properties) and i added these two lines and it solved the problem :

log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Answer (score 0):

For my case `log4j.properties` file is located at `/etc/hadoop/conf/`
Then add below configs as recommended

```
log4j.appender.RFA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.RFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```